# one sql query for all count of posts each day

Tags: mysql, count

I have been trying to make one generic query in which i'll get the `(Count of number of posts being submitted each day (separately) in a respective month count(postid))`

Like lets suppose month is january so query returns something like following.

*Output from one sql query:*

Day   :   Nummber of posts

1                      5

2                       3

3                       9

and so on..

Kindly let me know what is a right way to do that or any other good generic alternative, I am trying to avoid making multiple queries to count post for each respective day.

Table Structure:
`ID | postid | post | date`

```
Select count(postid) from posts where month="JAN"
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how your DB is structured, a generic query woudl look something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(postdate) AS year, MONTH(postdate) AS month,
    DAY(postdate) AS day, COUNT(postid) AS count
FROM posts
GROUP BY YEAR(postdate), MONTH(postdate), DAY(postdate)
ORDER BY year, month, day
```

Comment: i tried your query its correct but its returning the total number of posts in respective month and one row only. What i want is count for number of posts being made each day separately so that i can have a record of submitted posts day wise in entered month .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `date` column type named `nibbles`:

```
SELECT DAY(nibbles) AS day, COUNT(*) AS post_count
FROM sparkles
WHERE YEAR(nibbles) = 2012 AND MONTH(nibbles) = 1
GROUP BY DAY(nibbles)
```

**Update**

Using OP's updated table structure...

```
SELECT DAY(`date`) AS day, COUNT(post_id) AS post_count
FROM sparkles
WHERE YEAR(`date`) = 2012 AND MONTH(`date`) = 1
GROUP BY DAY(`date`)
```