# Number of Posts as per days in a month

Tags: mysql, count

There is a table `Post` in my database which contains posts of different users. What I wanna do is to create an sql query that'll return as per respective month the number of posts being made each day. Kindly let me know how can i do that generically in one query i can create multiple queries for all days but that is a worst case scenario. So I need expert's solution to this.
Thanks

**Expected output:**
(Query counts the number of posts for all the days in a respective month)

Day   :   Number of posts

1       :        20

2       :        25

3       :        10

4       :        17

.........................

30       :        6

Table Structure:
`ID | postid | post | date`

Comment: Did you try anything? At least, you should provide the relevant table definitions, e.g. 'USER' and 'POST'.

Comment: I tried but i ended up counting number of posts for single day only and not for all days in a month

Comment: possible duplicate of [one sql query for all count of posts each day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297465/one-sql-query-for-all-count-of-posts-each-day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DAYOFMONTH(date), count(*) FROM Post
GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(date)
ORDER BY DAYOFMONTH(date) ASC;
```

If you want to query for a specific month (say, February) then use this:

```
SELECT DAYOFMONTH(date), count(*) FROM Post
WHERE MONTH(date) = '2'
GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(date)
ORDER BY DAYOFMONTH(date) ASC;
```

Note: Months are returned in number form where the [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function is used.

**EDIT**: If you're looking to return counts for EVERY day in a given month, then I'd push you here - a great accepted answer to a similar question: [How to get values for every day in a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274777/how-to-get-values-for-every-day-in-a-month)

Comment: The query is returning number of posts for single day only from entire month

Comment: I am expecting for all days the query returns count of posts like if month is feb then it counts first for day 1 number of posts then day 2 and so on

Comment: Do you mean return counts for all days even if they are '0'?

Comment: yes something like day 1 = 24, day 2 = 25, day 3 = 0, day 4 = 5, and so on

Comment: That's actually more challenging in SQL alone (without say using PHP), so better to point you at this question and great answer: [How to get values for every day in a month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274777/how-to-get-values-for-every-day-in-a-month). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
select DAYOFMONTH(date) as Day , count(*) as Number_of_posts
from table
group by DAYOFMONTH(date)
```

You should know that if table contains data from different months number of posts will be wrong.
So the group by should be by date and you should use date in selected instead of day of month.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date, COUNT(id) as number_of_posts FROM table_name GROUP BY date.
```